# How do I display database query statistics on Wordpress site?

Tags: mysql, performance, wordpress, layout, statistics

I've noticed that a few Wordpress blogs have query statistics present in their footer that simply state the number of queries and the total time required to process them for the particular page, reading something like:

> 23 queries. 0.448 seconds

I was wondering how this is accomplished.  Is it through the use of a particular Wordpress plug-in or perhaps from using some particular php function in the page's code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try adding this to the bottom of the footer in your template:

```
<?php echo $wpdb->num_queries; ?> <?php _e('queries'); ?>. <?php timer_stop(1); ?> <?php _e('seconds'); ?>
```

Comment: or wp-admin/admin-footer.php if you want it to show in the backend admin panel.

Answer (score 6):

To explain pix0r's code:

- `$wpdb->num_queries` is the number of database queries.
- `_e` is for localization:  http://faq.wordpress.net/view.php?p=50
- `timer_stop()` returns the amount of time taken to render the page: 
   http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/timer_stop

Answer (score 1):

wordpress has a easy solution now

There is a function called [`get_num_queries()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_num_queries) and as specified in other answers [`timer_stop()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/timer_stop).

```
<?php echo get_num_queries(); _e(' queries'); ?> in <?php timer_stop(1); _e(' seconds'); ?></p>
```

`get_num_queries()` - returns the number of database queries during the WordPress execution and accepts no parameters

Comment: Is there a way to put this in the backend admin panel too?

Comment: `get_num_queries()` function is a global function. The above snippet should work in backend admin panel (wp-admin area).

Comment: Thanks.  The best place for this is at the end of wp-admin/admin-footer.php