# How to display all database queries made by Wordpress?

Tags: database, wordpress

Using a method similar to the one [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873/how-do-i-display-database-query-statistics-on-wordpress-site), I can see the total number of queries being made in Wordpress when I load a page.

Now I'd like to display all database queries that are being made when a page loads. This would allow me to see who my biggest resource hogs are, without having to go through the process of elimination of all my plugins and theme scripts.

What would be the best way to display all database queries made by Wordpress?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you add `define('SAVEQUERIES', true)` to your configuration file, you can then list all the queries made for the current page by adding the following to your theme.

```
if (current_user_can('administrator')){
    global $wpdb;
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($wpdb->queries);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

See the documentation for more details: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Save_queries_for_analysis

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick.  Now I just need to make sense of the queries.

Comment: Just a note that if you use Hyperdb, you need to do this in the db-config.php: $wpdb->save_queries = defined('SAVEQUERIES') && SAVEQUERIES;

Comment: can you say me what the [1] value is from each querie? [1] => 0.0004429817199707

Comment: The documentation has moved to https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#save-queries-for-analysis

Answer (score 7):

or you can hook into posts_request. You can put the coe inside functions.php such as

```
add_filter('posts_request','debug_post_request'); // debugging sql query of a post

function debug_post_request($sql_text) {

   $GLOBALS['debugku'] = $sql_text; //intercept and store the sql<br/>
   return $sql_text; 

}
```

in your theme footer, you can use print_r like

```
print_r($GLOBALS['debugku']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I like that this didn't require editing core files, and I think it worked, but I'm not 100% sure.  It was a little hard to decipher what it output.  The data seemed to be sparce, but I think that it might have all been on one line and I just couldn't see it all.  I went with Richard M's suggestion above and it outputed it all into a nicely formated list.

Comment: hei, like the old wisdom saying : There plenty road to Rome ;D

Answer (score 3):

Use [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/).

It's a free and open-source plugin where you can filter your queries in various contexts, such as:

- Which plugin called
- Queries that took the most time
- Duplicated queries
- You can filter by Select / Update / Insert / Delete

Among other things...

[image: how to see what queries wordpress is running]

Comment: There is an amazing amount of information in this plugin! I found the SQL I was looking for under Queries, Caller = Main Query.

Answer (score 1):

I like to add at the bottom of the page, queries/elapsed time, here the code:

```
/**
 * show all sql at footer if it defined in wp-config.php:
 * define('SAVEQUERIES', true);
 */
function plg_name_show_debug_queries()
{
    if (defined('SAVEQUERIES') && SAVEQUERIES) {
        global $wpdb;
        if (is_array($wpdb->queries)) foreach ($wpdb->queries as $key => $q) {
            list($query, $elapsed, $debug) = $q;
            $time = number_format(($elapsed * 1000), 3);
            $count = $key + 1;
            $total_time += $elapsed;
            echo "
            <div style=\"position: relative; z-index: 9999    ; background: black; color: white; padding:10px\">
                $count - Query: $query <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Time: $time ms
            </div>";
        }
        echo "
        <div style=\"position: relative; z-index: 9999    ; background: black; color: white; padding:10px\">
            Total Queries: " . count($wpdb->queries) . "<br>Total Time: " . number_format(($total_time * 1000), 3) . " ms
        </div>";
    }
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'plg_name_show_debug_queries', PHP_INT_MAX);
add_action('wp_footer', 'plg_name_show_debug_queries', PHP_INT_MAX);
```