# Setting Tax Query in pre_get_posts still showing products with the wrong taxonomy

Tags: php, search, woocommerce, wordpress

So basically I am using the following code which seems to be putting everything into the query perfectly however, I am still getting the wrong products. For example, I am requesting products with product category 'winter' but still receiving products in category 'all-season'

Here is my code:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'advanced_search_query', 1000);
function advanced_search_query($query) {
if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() ) {
    global $wp_query;
    // category terms search
    $categories = array('winter','all-season','summer','run-flat');
    $category = $_GET['category'];
    $categories = array_diff($categories,array($category));
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';
    if (isset($category) && !empty($category)) {
        $args = array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $category,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array($categories),
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        );
        $query->set('tax_query', $args);
        print_r($query);
    }
    return $query;
    }
}
```

The print_r returns the following:

> WP_Query Object (
>       [query] => Array
>           (
>               [s] => 2457516
>               [post_type] => product
>           )
>
> ```
> [query_vars] => Array
>     (
>         [s] => 2457516
>         [post_type] => product
>         [error] => 
>         [m] => 
>         [p] => 0
>         [post_parent] => 
>         [subpost] => 
>         [subpost_id] => 
>         [attachment] => 
>         [attachment_id] => 0
>         [name] => 
>         [static] => 
>         [pagename] => 
>         [page_id] => 0
>         [second] => 
>         [minute] => 
>         [hour] => 
>         [day] => 0
>         [monthnum] => 0
>         [year] => 0
>         [w] => 0
>         [category_name] => 
>         [tag] => 
>         [cat] => 
>         [tag_id] => 
>         [author] => 
>         [author_name] => 
>         [feed] => 
>         [tb] => 
>         [paged] => 0
>         [comments_popup] => 
>         [meta_key] => total_sales
>         [meta_value] => 
>         [preview] => 
>         [sentence] => 
>         [fields] => 
>         [menu_order] => 
>         [category__in] => Array
>             (
>             )
>
>         [category__not_in] => Array
>             (
>             )
>
>         [category__and] => Array
>             (
>             )
>
>         [post__in] => Array
>             (
>             )
>
>         [post__not_in] => Array
>             (
>             )
>
>         [tag__in] => Array
>             (
>             )
>
>         [tag__not_in] => Array
>             (
>             )
>
>         [tag__and] => Array
>             (
>             )
>
>         [tag_slug__in] => Array
>             (
>             )
>
>         [tag_slug__and] => Array
>             (
>             )
>
>         [post_parent__in] => Array
>             (
>             )
>
>         [post_parent__not_in] => Array
>             (
>             )
>
>         [author__in] => Array
>             (
>             )
>
>         [author__not_in] => Array
>             (
>             )
>
>         [orderby] => menu_order title
>         [order] => ASC
>         [meta_query] => Array
>             (
>                 [0] => Array
>                     (
>                         [key] => _visibility
>                         [value] => Array
>                             (
>                                 [0] => visible
>                                 [1] => search
>                             )
>
>                         [compare] => IN
>                     )
>
>                 [1] => Array
>                     (
>                         [key] => _stock_status
>                         [value] => instock
>                         [compare] => =
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>         [posts_per_page] => 12
>         [wc_query] => product_query
>         [tax_query] => Array
>             (
>                 [relation] => AND
>                 [0] => Array
>                     (
>                         [taxonomy] => product_cat
>                         [field] => slug
>                         [terms] => winter
>                         [operator] => IN
>                     )
>
>                 [1] => Array
>                     (
>                         [taxonomy] => product_cat
>                         [field] => slug
>                         [terms] => Array
>                             (
>                                 [1] => all-season
>                                 [2] => summer
>                                 [3] => run-flat
>                             )
>
>                         [operator] => NOT IN
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>     )
>
> [tax_query] => WP_Tax_Query Object
>     (
>         [queries] => Array
>             (
>             )
>
>         [relation] => AND
>         [table_aliases:protected] => Array
>             (
>             )
>
>         [queried_terms] => Array
>             (
>             )
>
>         [primary_table] => 
>         [primary_id_column] => 
>     )
>
> [meta_query] => 
> [date_query] => 
> [post_count] => 0
> [current_post] => -1
> [in_the_loop] => 
> [comment_count] => 0
> [current_comment] => -1
> [found_posts] => 0
> [max_num_pages] => 0
> [max_num_comment_pages] => 0
> [is_single] => 
> [is_preview] => 
> [is_page] => 
> [is_archive] => 1
> [is_date] => 
> [is_year] => 
> [is_month] => 
> [is_day] => 
> [is_time] => 
> [is_author] => 
> [is_category] => 
> [is_tag] => 
> [is_tax] => 
> [is_search] => 1
> [is_feed] => 
> [is_comment_feed] => 
> [is_trackback] => 
> [is_home] => 
> [is_404] => 
> [is_comments_popup] => 
> [is_paged] => 
> [is_admin] => 
> [is_attachment] => 
> [is_singular] => 
> [is_robots] => 
> [is_posts_page] => 
> [is_post_type_archive] => 1
> [query_vars_hash:WP_Query:private] => ac61ad4fe3856f3f91e2ca85a7e667a1
> [query_vars_changed:WP_Query:private] => 
> [thumbnails_cached] => 
> [stopwords:WP_Query:private] => 
> [compat_fields:WP_Query:private] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => query_vars_hash
>         [1] => query_vars_changed
>     )
>
> [compat_methods:WP_Query:private] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => init_query_flags
>         [1] => parse_tax_query
>     )
> ```
>
> )

SQL queries:

> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  itq2_posts.ID FROM itq2_posts  INNER JOIN
>   itq2_term_relationships ON (itq2_posts.ID =
>   itq2_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN itq2_postmeta ON (
>   itq2_posts.ID = itq2_postmeta.post_id )  INNER JOIN itq2_postmeta AS
>   mt1 ON ( itq2_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )  INNER JOIN itq2_postmeta AS
>   mt2 ON ( itq2_posts.ID = mt2.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND (
>   itq2_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (300)    AND
>   itq2_posts.ID NOT IN (
>                 SELECT object_id
>                 FROM itq2_term_relationships
>                 WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (8,1901,1902,1905,1906,1907,1908,1909,1910,1911,1912,1913,1914,1915,1917,1919,1920,1921,1922,1923,1924,1925,1926,1927,1928,1929,1930,1931,1932,1933,1934,1935,1936,1937,1938,1939,1940,1941,1943,1945,1946,1947,1948,1949,1950,1951,1952,1953,1954,1955,1957,1959,1960,1962,1965,1968,1971,1974,1976,1979,1981,1982,1983,1985,1988,1990,1991,1992,1995,1997,1999,2002,2004,2005,2007,2010,2012,2014,2017,2020,2023,2769,2770,2776,2780,3421,3479,3529,3540,3543,3549,3555,3592,3600,3632,3725,3729,3734,3738,3775,3789,3882,3890)
>             ) ) AND (((itq2_posts.post_title LIKE '%2457516%') OR (post_excerpt
>   LIKE '%2457516%') OR (itq2_posts.post_content LIKE '%2457516%')))  AND
>   (    itq2_postmeta.meta_key = 'total_sales'    AND    ( 
>       ( mt1.meta_key = '_visibility' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('visible','search') ) 
>       AND 
>       ( mt2.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'instock' )   ) ) AND itq2_posts.post_type = 'product' AND (itq2_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR itq2_posts.post_status =
>   'private') GROUP BY itq2_posts.ID ORDER BY itq2_postmeta.meta_value+0
>   DESC, itq2_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 12

Comment: Your code looks to be correct, so I would check the SQL queries (just [print to the page](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2474320/1427161)) to make sure nothing else is modifying it. If you also add `echo "<pre>";` above your `print_r()` it will format the array more readably.

Comment: This is what I seem to be getting for the SQL queries, please see edit above. @doublesharp

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is woocommerce specific, but when I ran into this issue myself I found that woocommerce already builds an empty tax query into it's product query, so when you add set your tax query with `$query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );` it's essentially adding a redundant array into the query as the `tax_query` inside the array has already been converted into an `object` for use.

The work around this, all you need to do is grab the current tax query and add to it or adjust it instead of starting with a blank array. Doing it this way allows you to build on to an object that has already got everything else needed for the tax_query.

So building off of your example, instead of just creating a new variable called $args, we're going to grab the current `tax_query` and save it as `$args` and then build further into it like this:

```
if (isset($category) && !empty($category)) {
    $args = $query->get( 'tax_query', [] ); //this is the important part
    $args['relation'] => 'AND';
    $args[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $category,
        'operator' => 'IN'
    );
    $args[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array($categories),
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    );
);
$query->set('tax_query', $args);
```