# wordpress query , that shows featured products

Tags: php, wordpress

I Want show featured products but my query return nothing!
I featured one of my products but not shown any thing.

```
<?php
    $terms = array(
        "post_type" => "product",
        "orderby"     =>  "date",
        "order"       =>  "DESC",
        "posts_per_page" => 12,
        "meta_query" => array(array('key' => '_featured','value' => 'yes'))
         );
        $query = new WP_Query( $terms );
        while($query->have_posts()){
        $query->the_post();
        global $product;
?>
```

Thanks Also

Answer (score 0):

use short code [featured_products per_page="12" columns="4"]

or custom logic as :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_key' => '_featured',
    'meta_value' => 'yes',
    'posts_per_page' => 12
);

$featured_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ($featured_query->have_posts()) : 

    while ($featured_query->have_posts()) : 

        $featured_query->the_post();

        $product = get_product( $featured_query->post->ID );

        // Output product information here
        echo "<pre>";print_r($product);echo "</pre>";

    endwhile;

endif;

wp_reset_query(); // Remember to reset
```

Ref here : http://biostall.com/how-to-display-woocommerce-featureds-product-without-a-shortcode/

Comment: Thanks Bro shortcode worked but custom not worked! I want Use Custom type ? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Try debugger enabled and see what is the query fully formed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473079/how-to-display-all-database-queries-made-by-wordpress  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473079/how-to-display-all-database-queries-made-by-wordpress

Comment: I put this code and it worked. Initially i also didn't get the record because no products in the db is marked as Featured.  i beleive you are missing to add the featured flag part to 1 . Go to quick edit of any product and mark the checkbox as "Featured" . I used woocomerce to manage the products and this is how you need to make them as featured product  and also ensure you have the print_r statement to print the products object. Ref: http://www.modernmarketingpartners.com/set-featured-products-woocommerce/.